# does derivative of convergent function go to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

My question: if $f$ is differentiable and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = M$, does this imply that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$?

My thinking: there exists $X$ such that $\forall x,y>X$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ by the Cauchy criterion. Thus $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{x-y} = f'(d)< \epsilon$ for $d$ between $x$ and $y$.

I worry this won't hold if $x$ is extremely close to $y$ though.

Comment: That is a good kind of worry to have. It got you to ask this question here rather than immediately accepting a wrong argument for a wrong conclusion. Good for you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that statement is false. Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}\sin(x^3)$.

Since $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}\sin(x^3)\right| \le \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} = 0$, by the squeeze theorem, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\sin(x^3) = 0$.

However, $f'(x) = 3x\cos(x^3) - \dfrac{1}{x^2}\sin(x^3)$ which is unbounded as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Intuitively, the fluctuations are becoming extremely small but simultaneously extremely rapid. This intuition also suggests additional conditions one can require in order to get the result (for example, monotonicity).

Answer (score 5):

As already shown, you can easily find a function that fits your condition but whose derivative is unbounded as $x \to \infty.$

A more borderline case is $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin (x^2)}{x}.$

It is easy to show (by the squeeze theorem) that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0,$
but

$$ f'(x) = 2 \cos(x^2) - \frac{1}{x^2}\sin (x^2). $$

This quantity is bounded for large $x$ but it never converges.